# What the difference is between ramble and excursion?

Tags: meaning, difference, synonyms

Following [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/whats-the-difference-between-trip-and-excursion) question, I would like to understand what is the difference between ramble and excursion? Does ramble and excursion have the same meaning? When should I choose to use each of them?

Comment: [correction: I would like to understand what the difference **is** between ramble and etc.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such questions, it's best to look at dictionaries to see where the meanings overlap.

But in short, **a ramble** is typically an unhurried walk over an unplanned route, where the walkers decide as they proceed where they want to go and where/when to stop en route.

An excursion is an outing that can be on foot, on wheels or in a vehicle of some sort. It can be a visit to gardens, a museum, the coast, the mountains or any other attraction that is conducted by any means.

Comment: In short, an *excursion* has some planned purpose (an event or destination) while a *ramble* is a walk for the sake of walking.

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that the route of a ramble is unplanned. There are "rambling societies" in which people get together in groups and go on a "ramble" over a route which, in this context, has usually been planned in quite some detail, even to the times at which they are expected to arrive at the various hostelries en route.